# ofbiz : log4j error when add item to new order

Tags: log4j, ofbiz

I try to add item to new order in ofbiz (installed with gradlew)

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy
>       org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent.getThrownProxy(Log4jLogEvent.java:530)
>       org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent.serialize(Log4jLogEvent.java:651)``

I expect to get order created.

I get log4j error.

Comment: Are all necessary log4j jars in the output dir after building?

Comment: i don't see any jar in ofbiz sub folders, i install with this command: ./gradlew cleanAll loadDefault   found in this blog  https://medium.com/viithiisys/installation-steps-of-apache-ofbiz-16-0-in-ubuntu-2edc39e9c7e2